# Working with websocket in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket

I am tying to implement socket connection in ReactJs, I have read there documentation for how to implement more than one namespace in socket and this is how I did it after following there instructions

```
import {Manager} from "socket.io-client";

export const manager = new Manager(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_API, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  reconnection:true,
  autoConnect:true,
});

// add the namespace [namespace1,namespace2]
export const chatSocket = manager.socket("/namespace1");

export const notesSocket = manager.socket("/namespace2");

manager.open((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("socket connection error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("socket connection succeeded");
  }
});
```

now I am trying to use it like that in my react app is this right or I should use it in another way because I don't see any result from my console.log mehtod

```
  useEffect(() => {
    chatSocket.on('connect',() => {
      console.log('connected socket chat')
    })
    notesSocket.on('connect',() => {
      console.log('connected socket notes')
    })
  },[])
```